# Is it possible to start animating this text effect only when mouse is scrolled down to that particular section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a typing text effect made in HTML,CSS and JS. 
This is my code:

```js
(function($) {
  var s,
    spanizeLetters = {
      settings: {
        letters: $('.js-spanize'),
      },
      init: function() {
        s = this.settings;
        this.bindEvents();
      },
      bindEvents: function() {
        s.letters.html(function(i, el) {
          //spanizeLetters.joinChars();
          var spanizer = $.trim(el).split("");
          return '<span>' + spanizer.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
        });
      },
    };
  spanizeLetters.init();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Cutive Mono", monospace;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.sep {
  border: 0;
  width: 3em;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.mast {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #111;
}

.mast:after {
  z-index: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
}

.mast>header {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.mast__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}

.mast__header {
  padding: 5%;
}

.mast__title {
  font-family: "Cutive Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mast__title span {
  -webkit-animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
  animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
}

.mast__title span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.05s;
  animation-delay: 0.05s;
}

.mast__title span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.mast__title span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

.mast__title span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.mast__title span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

.mast__text {
  font-family: "Cutive Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: pre;
}

.mast__text span {
  -webkit-animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
  animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.05s;
  animation-delay: 0.05s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
  animation-delay: 0.35s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
  animation-delay: 0.55s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(13) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s;
  animation-delay: 0.65s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(14) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(15) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}

.mast__text span:nth-child(16) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes letter-glow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes letter-glow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="mast">
    <figure class="mast__bg" style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/1800/800?image=893)"></figure>
    <header class="mast__header">
      <h1 class="mast__title js-spanize">Sample</h1>
      <hr class="sep" />
      <p class="mast__text js-spanize">
        This is a sample</p>

    </header>
  </section>
</main>
```

I want the animation to start only when the mouse scrolls to that particular section. The problem is here that the animation begins as soon as the page is loaded and usually ends by the time someone scrolls to that section. I want the letters to start typing itself only when someone scrolls to that particular section of page. Since I'm a beginner I don't know much about this. Can someone help me do it?

Comment: on scroll, add class if the window offset top is equal to position of the component which you want to animate. Apply CSS animations to that class. So yes, it can be done.

Comment: I'm a beginner.. Can u please help me do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). It's a native `JavaScript` feature that you can use to add a `class` when an element (or elements) intersects the viewport. Here's an example with comments in the code. Scroll down to see it in action.

```js
function onEntry(entry) {
  entry.forEach(el => {
    if (el.isIntersecting) {
      el.target.classList.add("start");
    }
  });
}

// Instantiate a new Intersection Observer
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry);

// All elements with "js-spanize" class
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".js-spanize");

for (let elm of elements) {
  observer.observe(elm);
}
```

```css
@keyframes letter-glow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}

.js-spanize.start {
  animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="mast">
    <figure class="mast__bg" style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/1800/800?image=893)"></figure>
    <header class="mast__header">
      <h1 class="mast__title js-spanize">Sample</h1>
      <hr class="sep" />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum at assumenda, laudantium ratione rem animi consectetur aspernatur corrupti quis eos officiis libero nobis, beatae rerum inventore nisi repudiandae id dolorem!</span><span>Natus maxime dolores recusandae iusto omnis est eos deleniti odit nam officiis reiciendis tempore necessitatibus provident explicabo rerum nulla totam dolor non, a dolorem accusantium! Perspiciatis nostrum reiciendis nihil aperiam.</span></p>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed accusamus cupiditate, velit explicabo ut consequuntur nisi, id obcaecati temporibus magni autem? Nemo enim id quia ea beatae odio aut quo!</span><span>Aperiam dignissimos labore officiis incidunt nobis debitis molestiae quas, cupiditate harum eligendi vel quis ipsam amet in, culpa quod consequatur ipsum ex maxime! Aut sunt dolore odit exercitationem voluptatum rerum!</span></p>
      <p class="js-spanize">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et nostrum, voluptatem fugit repellendus in corrupti provident eum iure placeat dignissimos, rerum quisquam quibusdam beatae a? Voluptatem dignissimos ad temporibus nisi!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et nostrum, voluptatem fugit repellendus in corrupti provident eum iure placeat dignissimos, rerum quisquam quibusdam beatae a? Voluptatem dignissimos ad temporibus nisi!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et nostrum, voluptatem fugit repellendus in corrupti provident eum iure placeat dignissimos, rerum quisquam quibusdam beatae a? Voluptatem dignissimos ad temporibus nisi!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et nostrum, voluptatem fugit repellendus in corrupti provident eum iure placeat dignissimos, rerum quisquam quibusdam beatae a? Voluptatem dignissimos ad temporibus nisi!</p>      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>      assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>            
      <p class="mast__text js-spanize">
        This is a sample</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae dolor molestias cum quo aperiam praesentium, distinctio, ducimus repellendus atque odio pariatur! Optio totam repudiandae assumenda, asperiores inventore architecto et? Provident!</p>      
    </header>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: thank u. Now i am able to animate the heading on scroll, using your code. But it cant be applied to the paragraph below.

Comment: @Helen Which elements exactly are you trying to apply animations to on scroll? All `<p>`? Certain ones?

Comment: Please check my sample code above.. In that there is heading <h1 class="mast__title js-spanize">Sample</h1> and a paragraph <p class="mast__text js-spanize">
        This is a sample</p>. Both these texts animates (types on its own) even before someone scrolls to that particular section of page. I want both these to animate (type on its own) only when someone scrolls to that particular section of the page. I added your code and now the heading part is animating only on scroll. But its not working for the paragraph part

Comment: So, any element with an `js-spanize` class?

Comment: <p class="mast__text js-spanize"> This is a sample</p> yes

Comment: @Helen I adjusted my example to include everything with a `js-spanize` class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190278/discussion-between-andy-hoffman-and-helen).

Comment: thank u soo much. You saved me today :) It's working perfectly